# Quantum phase transition in 1D Ising model

Tags: quantum-spin

What are the steps to find the energy levels of 1D Quantum Ising Model in the limits of g>>1 and g<<1(paramagnetic and ferromagnetic, respectively) with the help of degenerate perturbation? 
(P.S - any other method than the Jordan-Wigner transformation method will be highly appreciated. Please provide proper explanation for the steps)